# Woocommerce - Adding Custom Fee Together in Cart

Tags: function, woocommerce, cart

I created a function for a custom field for a fee which also multiplies depending on the amount of people booking:

```
// Add Custom Field to Product under General
function create_extra_fee_field() {
    $args = array(
    'id' => 'park_fee',
    'label' => __( 'Natl Park Entrance Fee', 'tranq-lsx-child' ),
    'class' => 'tranq-custom-field',
    'desc_tip' => true,
    'description' => __( 'This sets the Fee that will be added to the car.', 'tranq-lsx-child' ),
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
   }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'create_extra_fee_field' );

   // Save Custom Field Data
   function save_extra_fee_field( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $title = isset( $_POST['park_fee'] ) ? $_POST['park_fee'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( 'park_fee', sanitize_text_field( $title ) );
    $product->save();
   }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_extra_fee_field' );

   // Add Custom Field to Cart Totals

   function woo_add_cart_fee() {

       global $woocommerce; 

       foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_items ){
           // Get the WC_Product object (instance)
           $product = $cart_items['data'];
           $product_id = $product->get_id(); // get the product ID
           $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'park_fee', true );
           $person = array_sum( $cart_items['booking']['_persons'] );
       }    
       $additional_fee_name = "Natl Park Entrance Fee";
       $extra_fee = $custom_field_value * $person;
       $addedFee = false;
       // first check to make sure it isn’t already there
       foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_fees() as $_fee )
       {
           if ($_fee->id == sanitize_title($additional_fee_name) )
           {
           $_fee->amount = (float) esc_attr( $extra_fee );
           }
       }
       if (!$addedFee)
       {
           $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __($additional_fee_name, "woocommerce"),
           $extra_fee, $additional_fee_taxable );
       }
   }

   add_action( "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals", "woo_add_cart_fee" );
```

The one product is making use of that custom fee while the other product isn't its set to 0

But when both are added to the cart the fee just shows 0.

Is there any way to add both park fees together?

Comment: The condition `!addedFee` is always going to be True, as `$addedFee = false` is set prior to the if condition. Not sure if this is the reason, but there's no point in having the if condition there.

Answer (score 0):

@Demonix,  it is because the `$custom_field_value` is being overwritten with a '0' value, as the function loops through the attached products.

If you add in a statement to check if the `park_fee` is an actual number before replacing `$custom_field_value`

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $custom_field_value = 0;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get the WC_Product object (instance)
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_id = $product->get_id(); // get the product ID

        $temp_value = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'park_fee', true );
        if ( false !== $temp_value && 0 !== $temp_value && '' !== $temp_value && '0' !== $temp_value ) {
            $custom_field_value = $temp_value;
        }
        $person = array_sum( $cart_item['booking']['_persons'] );
    }
    $additional_fee_name = "Natl Park Entrance Fee";
    $extra_fee = $custom_field_value * $person;
    $addedFee = false;
    // first check to make sure it isn’t already there
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_fees() as $_fee ) {
        if ($_fee->id == sanitize_title($additional_fee_name) ) {
            $_fee->amount = (float) esc_attr( $extra_fee );
        }
    }
    if (!$addedFee) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __($additional_fee_name, "woocommerce"),
        $extra_fee, $additional_fee_taxable );
    }
}
add_action( "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals", "woo_add_cart_fee" );
```